# how compare type in template django

Tags: python, django

Got code:

```
{% for type in foodtypesmain %}
    {{ type_id }}
    {{ type.id }}
    {% if type.id == type_id %}
         ...........
    {% else %}
        ...........
    {% endif %}
.........
```

answer in template:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

But! 1 not = 1 WTF?

I think that problem in anoter types str and ind how i can compare type.id with type_id

Comment: You're printing both above the if-block, what's in them; is it always failing the conditional or something? Your question is unclear.

Comment: What is `foodtypesmain`? It looks like when you say "type" you don't mean it in the same sense that [Python does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that `type.id` is an *int* whereas `type_id` may be a string. You may want to either convert the *int* into a *str* by using the `slugify` filter or convert *str* into an int by using the `|add:"0"`. Below are the complete versions:

```
{% if type.id|slugify == type_id %}
```

or

```
{% if type.id == type_id|add:"0" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was in types.... try check long with in int + html if was attr checked he is will checked your input ty for the all answers!